# PHP array with a nested foreach

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

I have a table with data from sql. Some of the columns in the db have more than 1 name. I have created an array from them but now I need to compare the two while creating a table.

```
$strArrayChildren = explode(',', $children);
$strArrayChildren = str_replace('and', '', $strArrayChildren);
$childCount = count($strArrayChildren);

$strArrayGrades = explode(',',$the_grades);
$strArrayGrades = str_replace('(', '', $strArrayGrades);
$strArrayGrades = str_replace(')', '', $strArrayGrades);

$grades ='';
foreach($strArrayChildren as $child){
    foreach($strArrayGrades as $grade){
       if(strpos($grade, $child) !== false){
            $grades = preg_replace('([a-z A-Z ()]+)', "", $grade);
        }elseif(strpos($grade, $child) !== true){
            $grades ='';
        }
   }
   echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>{$child}</td>";
      echo "<td>{$last_name}</td>";
      echo "<td>Child</td>";
      echo "<td>{$grades}</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
 }
```

When I run this code I get the grade of the student to match with the first name from the array, but then the rest of the grades keep trying to match with the first student even though there is a new row with a new name.

Any help would be great! Thank you!

Comment: `var_dump ($strArrayChildren)` at line 4 and `var_dump ($strArrayGrades)` at line 7. What do you have?

Comment: for 'var_dump ($strArrayChildren)' I get a bunch of the following: array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "Becky" [1]=> string(6) " Aaron" [2]=> string(6) " Luke" } for var_dump ($strArrayGrades) I get a bunch of the following: array(3) { [0]=> string(6) "Olivia" [1]=> string(5) " Alan" [2]=> string(6) " Jack" }

Comment: Can't see any grade information in these arrays. Also, there seams to be no relationship between these two!

Comment: Sorry the grade one is this,     array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "1 Becky" [1]=>     string(9) " 11 Aaron" } array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "12 Gertrude" } array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "6 Laura" } array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "1 Susan" } array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "11 Kerrie" } array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "2 Olivia" [1]=> string(7) " 2 Alan" } array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "3 Claire" } array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "1 Claire" } Not sure why the it didnt show the grade on the last one. The names are the relationship I am trying to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your database but this should work. I'm posting the response with static arrays.

```
<?php
$strArrayChildren = array("Becky"," Aaron"," Luke");
$the_grades = "9 (Susan), 5 (Luke)";
$strArrayGrades = explode(',',$the_grades);
echo "<html><body><table style='text-align: center; width: 400px;'>";
echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>Child</td>";
          echo "<td>Grade</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
foreach($strArrayChildren as $child){
    $grades = "";
    $child = trim($child);
    foreach($strArrayGrades as $key => $grade){
        if(strpos($grade, $child) > 0){
            $grades = intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $grade), 10);
        }
   }
   echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>{$child}</td>";
      echo "<td>{$grades}</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
 }
echo "</table></body></html>";
?>
```

**Explanation:**

1. you need to initialize `$grades` right after first loop start
2. There is no point to test both states of `strpos()` function
3. It's safe to check position of needle occurrence in the string (be grater than 0)
4. You need to change you regex for selecting numbers from an string.
5. Trim needle in `strpos()`; there are unwanted white space in some cases. Better to trim white spaces at the start of the loop

Comment: I copied the code into my editor and what you wrote works good. It only pulled from the second array when the name matched in the first. But when I edit my code to match I get the same problem I still have. It will only pull the first name in the grade array and then move to the next line and pull the first name there and so on. The data comes from sql db and each column of grades looks like this 9 (Susan), 5 (Luke). I use the explode to turn it into an array.  Is there a way to modify your code for this?

Comment: Edited my answer including the query response sample you sent.

Comment: Awesome! That did it, thank you so much, I've been working on this for a while now.